# setting up parity on windows

Tags: parity, windows

Trying to setup Parity and Kovan to use Melonport app. Downloaded latest stable version of Parity 2.0.7 from Github as instructed and double clicked parity.exe. Starts terminal session which seems to run endlessly - downloading, syncing blocks?

Although not explicitly instructed to do so I downloaded the .zip asset file for 
Parity-Ethereum-2.0.7 and placed the parity.exe file in this main folder. This is the only .exe in the entire folder structure yet various online instructions indicate a ptray.exe which I assume launches the graphical UI.
Also added the `--chain=kovan.json` line to shortcut.

I noted somewhere that the sync can take some time.
Do I just check back in the morning when sync is finished or am I missing critical setup files?

Thanks In advance